# BLE FLAG_WRITE without response?

Tags: micropython

im have problem in ubluetooth module.

Standard in the characteristics to write is: FLAG_WRITE (default with reposnse) how to call with without reponse?

(gatt server)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide some code.

Comment: So far I've tried ubluetooth, but there FLAG_WRITE has no option without response...

Comment: Hi @thomas you figure this out? If so share your answer. If not, can you post your actual code and I'm sure the community will help you out.

Comment: @thomas Micropython is very specific to the board being used. Can you tell us what board you are using?